# Vaadin 24 navigate to route not working in listener

Tags: vaadin

after migrating our project from 23.3/spring boot 2.7.7 to 24.0/spring boot 3 we have issue with navigate between route.

If I use

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate(File_Management.class);
```

everything is fine and all work as expected but if I use it inside a button listener (a menu button for example)

```
menuButton.addClickListener(event -> {
      UI.getCurrent().navigate(File_Management.class);
});
```

application logout and no error was thrown.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Matteo

Put here additional info

I've a MainLayout class

```
  @NoArgsCostructor
    @Route("")
    public class MainLayout extends FlexBoxLayout implements RouterLayout, afterNavigationObserver {
    
        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
          UI currentUI = UI.getCurrent();
          
          //DO SOME STUFF
    
          //OPEN HOME
          currentUI.access(() -> {
                 currentUI.navigate(Main_Dashboard.class);
          });

          menuButton.addClickListener(event -> {
              currentUI.access(() -> {
                     currentUI.navigate(File_Management.class);
              });
          });
        }
}
```

This Main_Dashboard class

```
@NoArgsCostructor
@Route(value = "mainDashboard", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class Main_Dashboard extends SplitViewFrame {


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
           [....]
           
    }
}
```

This File_Management class

```
@NoArgsCostructor
@Route(value = "fileManagement", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class File_Management extends SplitViewFrame {


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
           [....]
           
    }
}
```

Target class File_Management and Main_Dashboard have same behaviour.

On login I invoke MainLayout then redirect to homepage https://www.test.com/mainDashboard, everything works as expected.

When I click on menu button I should navigate to File_Management class but application logoff and go to login page but URL in browser is https://www.test.com/fileManagement (and not https://www.test.com/login as expected in a correct logout).

If I switch Main_Dashboard and File_Dashboard in currentUI.navigate(...) File_Dashboard class open now as expected and Main_Dashboard logoff :-/

No error log in org.springframework.security or in tomcat catalina.out log.
I've also tried to permitAll() in spring security (just to check if it's a permission issue) but nothing changes.

Before migrating to vaadin 24/springboot 3 everything goes with no issue with last vaadin 23 version (23.3.4)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "application logout and not error was
thrown"? Does it navigate to a logout endpoint instead? Or is the
session lost and you are redirected to the login? Have you checked the
logs of `org.springframework.security` what's going on?

Comment: I tried this in a Vaadin 24 app and I couldn't reproduce the behavior, so you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ollitietavainen I added more info on parent post. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you triggering navigion events in the `@PostConstruct`? Why would the menuButton need the current UI for access; isn't it attached at the point in time, when it can be clicked?

Comment: At this point I think, that this is X-Y-problem; you should create
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),
that shows your actual problem you are battling.

Comment: @cfrick I need PostCostruct because I need to inject a SessionBean with user preferences while initializing layout.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue.
It's not related to Vaadin but to spring boot migration from 2.7.7 to 3.0 (and spring security from 5.8 to 6.0).

As explained here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html

spring SecurityContext default behaviour changed between spring 5 and 6.
In my case I checked if used is still logged in on page change using

```
public static boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        return authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated();
    }
```

It's ok on first request (after logging in) but on second request I get isAuthenticated() = false.

I added in Spring Security filterChain method

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        // ...
        .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
            .requireExplicitSave(false)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

and now works like a charm again.
Thank you!